# PHP Как вывести родителей определенного ITEM из дерева?

Tags: php, массивы, алгоритм, рекурсия

Есть массив связанный между собой (`id = parent_id`).

`parent_id` указывает `id` родителя.

```
<?php
    $arr = [
        [
            'id'        => 1,
            'parent_id' => 0,
            'sysname'      => 'AAA'
        ],
        [
            'id'        => 2,
            'parent_id' => 0,
            'sysname'      => 'BBB'
        ],
        [
            'id'        => 3,
            'parent_id' => 1,
            'sysname'      => 'AAA1'
        ],
        [
            'id'        => 4,
            'parent_id' => 3,
            'sysname'      => 'AAA11'
        ],
        [
            'id'        => 5,
            'parent_id' => 2,
            'sysname'      => 'BBB1'
        ]
    ];

    function CreateTree( $array,$sub=0, $tab='' )
    {
        $category=array();
        if( $sub > 0 )
        {
            $tab .= '-';
        }
        foreach( $array as $v )
        {
            if( $sub == $v['parent_id'])
            {
                $category[$v['id']]['id'] = $v['id'];
                $category[$v['id']]['parent_id'] = $v['parent_id'];
                $category[$v['id']]['sysname'] = $tab.$v['sysname'];
                $category += CreateTree($array, $v['id'], $tab);
            }
        }
        return $category;
    }
```

Функция  `CreateTree` Рисует дерево.

Следующая функция это дерево переворачивает `array_reverse`.Чтоб выводило родителей начиная с него по иерархии

```
    function getNavParentsByNavId( $navTree, $id )
    {
        $trees = array_reverse( $navTree );

        $newArr = [];
        foreach( $trees as $tree )
        {
            if( $tree['id'] == $id )
            {
                $newArr[$tree['id']] = $tree['sysname'];
                while($current = current($trees))
                {
                    $next = next($trees);
                    if($current['parent_id'] == $next['id'])
                    {
                        $newArr[$next['id']] = $next['sysname'];
                    }
                }
            }
            next($trees);
        }
        return $newArr;
    }

    $navTree = CreateTree($arr);

    echo '<pre>';

    print_r($navTree);
    print_r(getNavParentsByNavId($navTree, 4));
```

Функция `getNavParentsByNavId` должен вывести ту часть где `id` равно переданному значению и после него пока есть у него родители .

То Есть результат должен выглядеть

```
AAA11
AAA1
AAA
```

Но что то не получается.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
$arr = [
    [
        'id'        => 1,
        'parent_id' => 0,
        'sysname'      => 'AAA'
    ],
    [
        'id'        => 2,
        'parent_id' => 0,
        'sysname'      => 'BBB'
    ],
    [
        'id'        => 3,
        'parent_id' => 1,
        'sysname'      => 'AAA1'
    ],
    [
        'id'        => 4,
        'parent_id' => 3,
        'sysname'      => 'AAA11'
    ],
    [
        'id'        => 5,
        'parent_id' => 2,
        'sysname'      => 'BBB1'
    ]
];

function CreateTree( $array,$sub=0, $tab='' )
    {
        $category=array();
        if( $sub > 0 )
        {
            $tab .= '-';
        }
        foreach( $array as $v )
        {
            if( $sub == $v['parent_id'])
            {
                $category[$v['id']]['id'] = $v['id'];
                $category[$v['id']]['parent_id'] = $v['parent_id'];
                $category[$v['id']]['sysname'] = $tab.$v['sysname'];
                $category += CreateTree($array, $v['id'], $tab);
            }
        }
        return $category;
    }

function get_key($arr, $id)
{
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        if ($val['id'] === $id) {
            return $key;
        }
    }
    return null;
}

function getParentsById($arr, $id, $response=[])
{
    $key = get_key($arr, $id);
    $response[] = $arr[$key];
    if ($arr[$key]['parent_id'] != 0)
    {
        $response = getParentsById($arr, $arr[$key]['parent_id'], $response);
    }
    return $response;
}

$navTree = CreateTree($arr);

print_r($navTree);
print_r(getParentsById($navTree, 4));
```

[Пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/961db7be29c694dbb39a1045e25d33b3baf55443)

Если только названия:

```
function getParentsById($arr, $id, $response=[])
{
    $key = get_key($arr, $id);
    $response[] = $arr[$key]['sysname'];
    if ($arr[$key]['parent_id'] != 0)
    {
        $response = getParentsById($arr, $arr[$key]['parent_id'], $response);
    }
    return $response;
}
```

[Пример](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/56440194e7f909daf30dcc084b295d904ec5f9cb)

Ну и так же для начального массива можно вызвать

```
getParentsById($arr, 4)
```

Comment: `get_key ` Fatal error: Call to undefined function get_key()

Comment: ну так может стоит добавить функцию `get_key` которую я написал в примере?

Comment: Извини не заметил :)